# geth Fatal: Failed to unlock developer account

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

I'm trying to start `geth` 1.8.1-stable-1e67410e with the following command:

```
geth --datadir="/custom-folder-path" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpc --dev --mine --minerthreads 2 --rpcapi="debug,db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --unlock "0x42d9fa1776d5041d78e13549f295601d496b297f,c5a3b476d3f0ac4ee02cc74a03e73c9bad186b32,0481de49674c6b122fcc64bcb16396b1ada47107,c682648c18cd05f46a6e927ee057f58f92e2ca7f" --password "dev-blockchain-1-pwd" --ipcpath "/custom-ipc-path"
```

with the file `dev-blockchain-1-pwd` containing the four passwords:

```
asdasdasdasdasdasd1
asdasdasdasdasdasd2
asdasdasdasdasdasd3
asdasdasdasdasdasd4
```

In the past this command successfully fired up a local blockchain, but now it outputs the following

```
INFO [02-19|14:55:44] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
Fatal: Failed to unlock developer account: could not decrypt key with given passphrase
```

I've successfully unlocked the JSON wallet files on myetherwallet.com with the passwords in the `dev-blockchain-1-pwd`.

Have you got any clue on how to deal with this? Thank you

Comment: Update: no solution found as of 2018-05-28, but I've also moved to other stuff in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

`geth --dev` creates a preconfigured private network, so --unlock and --password don't work.

If you want them to work, create a new private network and `geth init` it with a custom genesis.json.

Comment: geth --datadir data --networkid 15 --http --http.corsdomain="https://remix.ethereum.org" --http.api web3,eth,debug,personal,net --vmdebug --dev, it gives same error.